Green function of a differential equation
Let
$$
Lu(x)=a(x)\frac{d^2u(x)}{dx^2}+b(x)\frac{du(x)}{dx}+c(x)u(x),
$$
We define its Green function $G_0(x,y)$ by
$$
LG_0(x,y)=\delta_x(y)
$$
in the sense of distribution.
It's esay to get this Green function. Now I focus on construction of the Green function $G(x,y)$ of $\partial_y^2\circ L$, how to solve this question? is there any relation between $G_0(x,y)$ and $G(x,y)$?

It is to be noted that the operator $\Lambda = \partial_{yy} \circ L$ generates a PDE by acting on a bivariate function $u(x,y)$. In consequence, the associated fundamental solution $G(x,y;s,t)$ will satisfy $\Lambda G(x,y;s,t) = \delta_{x,y}^{(2)}(s,t) = \delta_x(s)\delta_y(t)$. If $G_0$ and $G_1$ denotes the Green functions of $L$ and $\partial_{yy}$ respectively, then one has $G(x,y;s,t) = G_0(x;s)G_1(y;t)$.
